# Implementing Fraction Abstract Class

Tags: python, fractions

I am having trouble trying to get the isZero, isNegative, reciprocal and the negate working. When I test them, I get "builtins.AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'reciprocal'."
Are these four functions implemented correctly?

My Code With What Each Section Should Do:

```
class Fraction:

    # Creates a new rational number from the supplied values. The denominator must be greater than zero
    def __init__( self, numerator = 0, demoninator = 1 ) :
        self._numerator = numerator
        self._demoninator = demoninator
        # Demoninator cannot be zero
        if demoninator == 0 :
            raise ZeroDivisionError("The demoninator cannot be zero.")

        # Rational number must be stored in its smallest reduced form 
        if numerator == 0 :
            self._numerator = 0
            self._demoninator = 1
        else :
            if (numerator < 0 and demoninator >= 0 or numerator >= 0 and demoninator < 0) :
                sign = -1
            else :
                sign = 1


    # Returns a Boolean indicating if the rational number is zero
    def isZero( self ) :
        if self != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False        

    #  Returns a Boolean indicating if the rational number is negative 
    def isNegative( self ) :
        if self < 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    #  Returns a new rational number that is the reciprocal of this rational number
    def reciprocal( self ) :
        reciprocal = 1 / self
        return reciprocal



    # Returns the floating-point representation of the rational number.
    # This operation is performed on the Fraction x by typecasting with the
    # float(x) function
    def __float__( self) :
        return self._numerator / self._denominator 

    # Compares this rational number to the rational number stored in
    # rhsFraction to determine their logical ordering
    def __eq__( self, rhsFraction ) :
        if self._numerator == rhsFraction._numerator and self._demonaitor ==    rhs.Frction._denominator :
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __lt__( self, rhsFraction ) :
        if self._numerator * rhsFraction._denominator < self._demoninator * rhsFraction._numerator :
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __le__( self, rhsFraction ) :
        return not rhsFraction < self 



    # Returns a new rational number that is the negative (-x) of this
    # rational number
    def negate( self ) :
        self = -self
        return self


    # Returns a new rational number that is the absolute version of this rational number.
    # Performed by applying the abs( x ) function to the Fraction x
    def __abs__( self ) :
        a = abs(numerator)           
        b = abs(denominator)         
        while a % b != 0 :             
            tempA = a              
            tempB = b             
            a = tempB             
            b = tempA % tempB           
        self._numerator = abs(numerator) // b * sign          
        self._denominator = abs(denominator) // b 

    # Creates and returns a new rational number that is the result of adding this rational
    # number to the given rhsFraction
    def __add__( self, rhsFraction) :
        num = (self._numerator * rhsFraction._denominator + self._denominator * rhsFraction._numerator)  
        den = self._denominator * rhsFraction._denominator       
        return Fraction(num, den) 

    # The same as the add() operation but subtracts the two rational numbers
    def __sub__( self, rhsFraction ) :
        num = (self._numerator * rhsFraction._denominator - self._denominator * rhsFraction._numerator)        
        den = self._denominator * rhsFraction._denominator       
        return Fraction(num, den) 

    # Creates and returns a new rational number that is the result of multiplying this
    # rational number to the given rhsFraction
    def __mul__( self, rhsFraction ) :
        n = self.__numerator * rhsFraction._numerator
        d = self.__denominator * rhsFraction._demoninator
        return Fraction(n, d)        

    # Creates and returns a new rational number that is the result of dividing this
    # rational number by the given rhsFraction. The rhsFraction can not be zero
    def __truediv__( self, rhsFraction ) :
        n = self._numerator / rhsFraction
        d = self._demoninator / rhsFraction
        return Fraction(n, d)

    # Returns a string representation of the rational number in the format #/#
    def __str__( self ) :
        return str(self._numerator) + "/" + str(self._demoninator)
```

My Code Test:

```
from fractions import Fraction

FractionA = (2,-2)
FractionB = (3,-4)
f1 = Fraction(2,-2)
f2 = Fraction(3,-4)
f3 = Fraction.__add__(f1,f2)
f4 = Fraction.__sub__(f1,f2)
f5 = Fraction.__mul__(f1,f2)
f6 = Fraction.__truediv__(f1,f2)
f8 = 0
       print(Fraction.__str__(f3),Fraction.__str__(f4),Fraction.__str__(f5),Fraction.__    str__(f6), Fraction.__str__(f1), Fraction.__str__(f2))


f11 = Fraction.__eq__(f1,f2)
print(f11)

f10 = Fraction.__lt__(f1,f2)
print(f10)

f12 = Fraction.__le__(f1,f2)
print(f12)

f13 = Fraction.__abs__(f1)
print(f13)

f14 = Fraction.__abs__(f2)
print(f14)

f15 = f1.reciprocal(f1)
print(f15)
```

Error:
3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[evaluate testfrac.py]
-7/4 -1/4 3/4 4/3 -1 -3/4
False
True
True
1
3/4
Traceback (most recent call last):

builtins.AttributeError: 'Fraction' object has no attribute 'reciprocal'

Comment: you know there are builtins for this https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html

Comment: the builtins in fact have exactly the same name as your module and class, so you're actually getting the builtins when you run `import fractions`, which is why your Fraction object doesn't support `reciprocal`.

Comment: @JoranBeasley that bulletin does not help me, that is why the questioned is posted

Comment: @lindsey the fact that you've imported the built ins and are using custom functions with the built in names is probably part of your problem.

Comment: it is not the problem, remove it or leave it...the same problem

Comment: you have a tuple not a fraction that you are trying to call it on ...

Comment: so how do I not do that? I am asking for someone to SHOW rather than say

Comment: no one can show you ... since you are clearly leaving some code you are using out ... you need to provide a fully runnable example ...

Comment: `Fraction(6,7).isZero()` works fine ... (other than giving the wrong answer)

Comment: i added my test code

Comment: While throwing various Errors I can't reproduce your specific error. Can you post the exact traceback?

Answer (score 1):

`fractions` is also the name of an builtin library of python, also see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html). So you are in fact not testing your fractions class but the builtin. But that does not provide the `reciprocal` you try call. Name your file something different e.g. `myfractions` and then import that by

```
from myfractions import Fractions
```

and run your tests again.

Comment: now i get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 7, in <module>
   line 101, in __add__
    num = (self._numerator * rhsFraction._denominator + self._denominator * rhsFraction._numerator)
builtins.AttributeError: 'Fraction' object has no attribute '_denominator'

Comment: Spelling error, you are setting `self._demoninator`. Be sure to double check your variable names.

Comment: I checked the spelling and changed it but now I get:  line 101, in __add__
    num = (self._numerator * rhsFraction._denominator + self._denominator * rhsFraction._numerator)
builtins.AttributeError: 'Fraction' object has no attribute '_denominator'

Comment: Without seeing your code I can not help you further. It looks like you still somehow import the builtin `Fraction` class. Do you understand what the error is saying? You might want to ask a new question if you can't find a solution for yourself. Reading [this stackoverflow help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can help you ask clearer/better questions. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is help for formatting your posts better, so others can help you quicker.